# Manage.py runserver for demonstration

Tags: python, django

How would I run a Django application on, a digitalocean droplet let's say, with just using the development server Django provides. I've tried just running python3 manage.py runserver, but I can't pull it up with the browser from another computer

I know this is bad practice, but I really only need it up to demonstrate for a class project

Comment: Have you read the output immediately following startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python3 manage.py runserver <your IP address>:8000`

Answer (score 3):

by default runserver only listn on 127.0.0.1 that is not accessible from remote computer.

run

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

will solve it, simply check the real IP if the machine and use it as address in your browser